# Open folder with * instead of the whole folder name

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I want to open a folder by not using the whole foldername.

The Foldername is 219448_CustomerName

But I don´t know the CustomerName so I just want to use the number 219448 with * in the end.

Is this possible?

I´m using it like this, but it´s not working.

```
Call Shell("explorer.exe" & " " & "G:\Money\Credit Assessment\Customer\219448*", vbNormalFocus)
```

If I run it like this, the Explorer is just opening "MyDocuments".

I also want to add another folder behind the star to go deeper like:

```
Call Shell("explorer.exe" & " " & "G:\Money\Credit Assessment\Customer\219448*\Info", vbNormalFocus)
```

Comment: I've no idea how you have a folder with * as I didn't think it was possible. However, in VBA/Excel you can put a tilde in front of a wildcard character to prevent it acting as a wildcard. So * becomes ~*

Comment: I want to open a folder where I don´t know the exactly Name that´s why I thought about to use the * in my Shell Operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shell does not support paths where wildcards represent directory names.

There can be multiple wildcard matches for such a path, so what would explorer.exe do with 50 different paths?

If you want to actually do this, you will need to manually locate a concrete path from the wildcard and pass that to explorer.

Example:

```
'wildcard must be in the last path-part, no trailing \
inputPath = "G:\Money\Credit Assessment\Customer\219448*"

'get fixed path
fixedPath = Left$(inputPath, InStrRev(inputPath, "\"))
'wildcard part
wildPath = Mid$(inputPath, InStrRev(inputPath, "\") + 1)

'//loop fixed path looking for a wildcard match on subdirs
aDir = Dir$(fixedPath & "*.*", vbDirectory)
Do While Len(aDir)
    If aDir <> "." And aDir <> ".." And GetAttr(fixedPath & aDir) And vbDirectory Then
        If aDir Like wildPath Then
            MsgBox "found: " & fixedPath & aDir
        End If
    End If

    aDir = Dir$()
Loop
```

Comment: Wasn´t exactly what I wanted but it helps to reach my target, thanks a lot!